# Golang: How do I convert command line arguments to integers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, go, type-conversion, command-line-arguments

I want to make a script that does an insertion sort on the arguments provided by the user, like this:

```
    $ insertionSort 1 2 110 39
```

I expect it to return:

```
    [1 2 39 110]
```

But it returns:

```
    [1 110 2 39]
```

I think it's because the elements in the os.Args array are strings. So, my question is how do I convert the elements of the os.Args array into integers? Here's my code:

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
         "os"
         "reflect"
         "strconv"
    )

    func main() {
        A := os.Args[1:]

        for i := 0; i <= len(A); i++ {
          strconv.Atoi(A[i])
          fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(A[i]))
        }

         for j := 1; j < len(A); j++ {
             key := A[j]
             i := j - 1
             for i >= 0 && A[i] > key {
               A[i+1] = A[i]
               i = i - 1
               A[i+1] = key
             }
          }
        fmt.Println(A)
    }
```

As a heads up, when I substitute

```
     strconv.Atoi(A[i])
```

For

```
     A[i] = strconv.Atoi(A[i])
```

I get the following error:

```
    ./insertionSort.go:14: multiple-value strconv.Atoi() in single-value context
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Atoi](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) returns the number and an error (or nil) from

> ParseInt interprets a string s in the given base (2 to 36) and returns the corresponding value i. If base == 0, the base is implied by the string's prefix: base 16 for "0x", base 8 for "0", and base 10 otherwise.
>
> The bitSize argument specifies the integer type that the result must fit into. Bit sizes 0, 8, 16, 32, and 64 correspond to int, int8, int16, int32, and int64.
>
> **The errors that ParseInt returns have concrete type *NumError and include err.Num = s. If s is empty or contains invalid digits, err.Err = ErrSyntax and the returned value is 0;** if the value corresponding to s cannot be represented by a signed integer of the given size, err.Err = ErrRange and the returned value is the maximum magnitude integer of the appropriate bitSize and sign.

You need to do :

```
var err error
nums := make([]int, len(A))
for i := 0; i < len(A); i++ {
    if nums[i], err = strconv.Atoi(A[i]); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(nums[i])
}
```

Working example : http://play.golang.org/p/XDBA_PSZml

Comment: To add on this: "multiple-value XXXXXX in single-value context" *always* means you are not capturing (or explicitly ignoring with _) all of the return values from a function. In most cases it's where a function returns >= 2 values and you are only capturing one. A good editor will help with this as it will show you the function signature as part of autocomplete.